# Mat-Dialog is not showing in fullscreen mode of browser

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a component `viewImg` which has three parts as follows:

1. Header
2. Main view area
3. Footer

The header has two action icons: `delete` and `add`. The main area displays an image along with some action buttons which are `fullscreen` , `zoom-in` , and `zoom-out`. And the footer has submit, save, and preview buttons.

On clicking `delete` icon a `mat-dialog` is opened which asks whether to delete the image or not. This works perfectly fine when I'm working in the normal flow. But as soon as I click on the `fullscreen` action button in the main area. This entire component goes into fullscreen mode with all the three components. Now, in this fullscreen mode if I click on `delete` icon, it doesn't show up the `mat-dialog` . But as soon as I exit the fullscreen mode, I can see that `mat-dialog` opened.

I want the `mat-dialog` shown in the fullscreen mode as well. Can someone help me with this?

Here is the code-snippets for my components:

**viewImg Component (viewImg.component.html)**

```
<div class="container" #container>
  <div class="header-row flex-row ai-center">
    <div class="title">HelloWorld.jpg</div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <mat-icon
      class="btn-icon"
      aria-hidden="false"
      aria-label="delete resource"
      (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); deleteScript()"
    >
      delete
    </mat-icon>
    <mat-icon
      class="btn-icon"
      aria-hidden="false"
      aria-label="add resource"
      (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); openGalleryDialog()"
    >
      add
    </mat-icon>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="resource-scroll-container">
      <div
        class="resource-scale-container flex-row ai-center jc-center"
        [style.transform]="'scale(' + zoom + ')'"
        [style.transform-origin]="zoom > 1 ? '0 0' : 'inherit'"
      >
        <div class="resource-view-port">
          <div class="resource-wrapper">
            <div>
              <img
                #image
                class="resource-image"
                [src]="resource.url"
                (load)="onImageLoad()"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="toolkit-wrapper" [class.hide]="hideImage">
      <app-main-view
        (action)="onToolkitAction($event)"
        [cropAreaDrawn]="cropAreaDrawn"
      ></app-main-view>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="action-button-row flex-row">
    <button mat-flat-button class="btn-primary">Preview</button>
    <button mat-flat-button class="btn-primary">Save</button>
    <button mat-flat-button class="btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**viewImg Component (viewImg.component.ts)** (I'm including the required functions here. Please let me know if you need any other.)

```
@ViewChild("container", { static: true }) containerElem: ElementRef;

//function to fullscreen the component
private _fullScreen() {
    this.containerElem.nativeElement.requestFullscreen();
}

private _removeFullScreen() {
    document.exitFullscreen();
}

//function to open up the delete dialog box
deleteScript() {
    const self = this;
    this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
        data: {
            message: `Do you want to delete ?`,
            onConfirm: (cb) => {
                console.log("Deleted!");
                cb();
                self._changeDetectRef.detectChanges();
            },
            title: "Delete",
            trigger: this.containerElem,
        },
        autoFocus: false,
    });
    this._changeDetectRef.detectChanges();
}
```

**Delete Confirm Dialog Component (ConfirmDialog.component.html)**

```
<div class="confirm-dialog-content">
  <h2 *ngIf="data.title" mat-dialog-title>{{ data.title }}</h2>
  <mat-dialog-content>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="data.contentTemplate || defaultContentTemplate">
    </ng-container>
  </mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-dialog-actions>
    <button class="btn-rounded btn-secondary" mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="false">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn-rounded btn-primary" mat-button (click)="proceed()">{{data.yesText || 'Confirm'}}</button>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
</div>

<ng-template #defaultContentTemplate> {{ data.message }} </ng-template>
```

**Delete Confirm Dialog Component (ConfirmDialog.component.ts)**

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-confirm-dialog',
  templateUrl: './confirm-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confirm-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class ConfirmDialogComponent {

  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA)
    public data: { message: string; title?: string; onConfirm?: Function, contentTemplate?, yesText?: string },
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmDialogComponent>,
  ) {}

  proceed() {
    if (this.data.onConfirm) {
      this.data.onConfirm(() => {
        this.dialogRef.close('confirm');
      })
    } else {
      this.dialogRef.close('confirm');
    }
  }

}
```

Please help me find out how to show delete dialog on click of delete in fullscreen mode.

Also, let me know if you need anymore information.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### Fullscreen only dialogs container

Change this line `this.containerElem.nativeElement.requestFullscreen();` by `this.document.getElementsByClassName('cdk-overlay-container')[0].requestFullscreen();`

The idea to only do fullscreen the required container; in this case, the dialogs are inside div with class `cdk-overlay-container.`

[image]

### Original answer

Hi, you could found the answer on your `viewImg.component.ts` file on `_fullScreen` function.

Because you are asking for only the current dialog to go fullscreen, however, if you want other dialogs to go fullscreen too, you should request fullscreen from a container of both dialogs.

Change this line `this.containerElem.nativeElement.requestFullscreen();` by `this.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].requestFullscreen();`

Here is a minimal working example (it should works if you open on a new tab, not inside stackblitz):

- open a new tab: https://angular-ivy-knyuq6.stackblitz.io/
- source code stackblitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-knyuq6?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: But I want to use this component within another component. And I want to fullscreen only this component. But doing `this.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].requestFullscreen();` will increment the entire page instead of just `viewImg` component.

Comment: let me edit my answer. to only full screen the overlay container